# How do I stretch the shin muscles?

Tags: stretching, legs, shins

I have read an answer here suggesting that two muscles be stretched to avoid shin tightening.

I don't know how that works. How do I correctly stretch these muscles to avoid shin tightening?

Answer (score 2):

So the "shin" muscle everybody usually refers to is the anterior tibialis. Here are some stretches:

http://walking.about.com/od/stretching/a/shinstretch.htm

http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/stretch-anterior-tibialis-muscle-8489.html